# Facebook graph get likes/comments count of a post with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have tried many methods of doing this and all of them failed...

I'm using the facebook php sdk to create my own news feed(the feed comes from a page's timeline)

To get the likes in the facebook I use **$post['likes']** where **likes** would output:

```
"data": [
           {
              "id": "100001919135377",
              "name": "Person name"
           },
           {
              "id": "1153253855",
              "name": "Person name"
           },
           {
              "id": "100000945245573",
              "name": "Person name"
           },
           {
              "id": "100002595937528",
              "name": "Person name"
           },
           {
              "id": "100001873157306",
              "name": "Person name"
           },
           {
              "id": "1356273210",
              "name": "Person name"
           }
        ]
```

How can I count the number of likes and then echo that?

Same thing for comments, I use **$post['comments']** and it would output

```
"data": [
           {
              "id": "637555672952364_6191387",
              "from": {
                 "name": "Person Name",
                 "id": "1153253855"
              },
              "message": "Comment content",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2014-01-11T07:28:37+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
           },
           {
              "id": "637555672952364_6191388",
              "from": {
                 "name": "Person Name",
                 "id": "1153253855"
              },
              "message": "Comment content",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2014-01-11T07:28:39+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
           }
        ]
```

Same thing for this I would like to count the number of comments and echo it...

If you need to know more info please tellme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your data is in json form, did you try using json_decode("json string",true); this will give you an array and you can use some array manipulation to get the counts.

Comment: I am really noob beginner in PHP, don't know exactly how to do that... All I know is im supposed to count the number of objects where an object would be

{
         "id": "100002595937528",
         "name": "Person name"
}

Comment: Can you post your code in http://codepad.org/ and the desired output ?

Comment: My feed has its code but I currently have no code at all for what im asking here, this is why I'm asking the question :P I would just like to echo the number of comments and likes. To get this json data, I either do $post['comments'] or $post['likes']

Comment: http://codepad.org/Qtc4uf8c here is my full code, I want to add the post count where the comment //TEST LIKE COUNT is

Comment: I did not get your question but as far as getting the comments and likes are concern you need to use graph api and the returned data will be in json form and you can parse that to get whatever you want.

Comment: I see you have a $postCount++; you can use that variable to display the total count

Comment: That variable is used to count the number of posts in my feed and limit it to a certain number, not for likes or comments

Comment: Hmm you may need to loop through the other data to get the count..

Comment: I tried

    $like = 0;
    foreach($post['likes'] as $like)
    {
     $like++;
    }
    echo $like;

Comment: Yes if you have data in $post['likes'] you try as $like_count = 0 ; foreach($post['likes'] as $like){ $like_count++ ;} your example you are doing $like++ and its in the foreach also so you may not get the desired count.

Comment: This is getting nowhere...

Answer (score 2):

use the `count();` function to get the number of element that a `JSON` array has

Here's a simple `PHP` example with `file_get_contents`

```
<?php

function fetchUrl($url){

         return file_get_contents($url);

}

$authToken = "{Token}";

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{POST_ID}/likes?$authToken}&limit=5000"); // 

$feedarray   = json_decode($json_object, true);

$likesNum = count($feedarray['data']); // return the number of items in `data` array

print $likesNum;

?>
```

same thing works for comments as well

Answer (score 2):

Try using the comments.summary(true) in the api call

eg [Adding count to the comments](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=80apps%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dlikes.summary%281%29%2Ccomments.summary%281%29)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a easy way to get facebbok like count from Facebook

```
<?php
    function fetchUrl($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }

    $authToken = "{token}"; // Authentication Token
    $facebookUrl = "{page name only}"; // https://www.facebook.com/page name
    $json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/$facebookUrl/?fields=fan_count&access_token=$authToken");

    $feedarray   = json_decode($json_object, true);

    echo number_format($feedarray['fan_count'],0,",","' "); // Will display count : 00'000
    echo $feedarray['fan_count']; // Will display count : 00000
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{POST_ID}/likes?field=total_count");
```